# how to get and edit specific value of xml

Tags: c#, xml

Is that possible to get and edit specific value of xml by using asp.c#?
For example, my xml file:

```
<posters>
  <poster>
    <quantity>100</quantity>
    <stock>100</stock>
    <price>88</price>
  </poster>
  <poster>
    <quantity>100</quantity>
    <stock>150</stock>
    <price>95</price>
  </poster>
  <poster>
    <quantity>200</quantity>
    <stock>100</stock>
    <price>95</price>
  </poster>
  <poster>
    <quantity>200</quantity>
    <stock>150</stock>
    <price>100</price>
  </poster>
</posters>
```

There are two 95s from quantity == 200 & stock == 100 and quantity == 100 &stock == 150.
Can I just get the value 95 from quantity == 200 and stock == 100 and edit it without modifying the same 95 from quantity == 100 &stock == 150?

I tried to use "SelectSingleNode" and "SelectNode" but they can't help me.
I want to get the result like sql -- "select price from poster where quantity = 200 and stock = 100".

Any suggestions?

Xml to dataset:

```
string xmlDocString = Server.MapPath("MyXMLFile.xml");
    DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
    dataSet.ReadXml(xmlDocString);
    GridView1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[0].DefaultView;
    GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: Could you show us the code, you use to read XML already?

Comment: You probably want to look at LINQ to Datasets http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386910.aspx or XPath if it's just plain XML text http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387050.aspx

Comment: IMHO, your XML sux. How do you know what 'poster' those numbers are for? It's just not descriptive enough. You need something like a <name> element or attribute to identify each <poster>. That way, you can easily pull information out of it using linq or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an XPath expression, and [this XML Library](https://github.com/ChuckSavage/XmlLib/):

```
int quantity = 200;
int stock = 100;
int newPrice = 55;
XElement root = XElement.Load(file);
XElement poster = root.XPathElement("//poster[quantity={0} and stock={1}]", 
                                    quantity, stock);
poster.Set("price", newPrice, false); // false for set child ELEMENT value
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx).  It will allow you to have code "like sql"

Here is an example of your code that works in LINQPad

```
void Main()
{
    var xml = @"<posters>
  <poster>
    <quantity>100</quantity>
    <stock>100</stock>
    <price>88</price>
  </poster>
  <poster>
    <quantity>100</quantity>
    <stock>150</stock>
    <price>95</price>
  </poster>
  <poster>
    <quantity>200</quantity>
    <stock>100</stock>
    <price>95</price>
  </poster>
  <poster>
    <quantity>200</quantity>
    <stock>150</stock>
    <price>100</price>
  </poster>
</posters>";

    var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

var value = (from x in doc.Descendants("poster")
        where x.Element("stock").Value == "100" 
        && x.Element("quantity").Value == "200"
        select x.Element("price")).FirstOrDefault();

    if (value != null)
        value.SetValue("1000");

    value.Dump();
    doc.Dump();
}
```